# Accessing a GWT Servlet from a seperate GWT client

Tags: gwt, netbeans

I am using NetBeans for my IDE and GlassFish 3.1.2 for my server.

I’ve written a trivial GWT project (GWTServer) which provides a GWT RPC Service named GWTService (all the service does is concatinate a string to what is passed in and return it).  I have written a SEPERATE client project (GWTClient) that I want to access the server GWT RPC Service.   NetBeans has generated some client code in GWTServer that can be used to access the RPC Service.

My server GWT project is deployed on glassfish and accessable through “localhost:8080/GWTServer”.

I am having problems doing  a couple of things that I need to make this work:

First, GWTServer has a couple of generated classes I need to use in GWTClient.  These classes are GWTService and GWTServiceAsync.  I need to (preferably) get the IDE to compile these into a jar file that I can include in GWTClient.  I’ve tried creating a java library project, copying these 2 java files into the library and including that library in GWTClient but this gives me an error:   “No source code is available for type org.gwtserver.client.GWTServiceAsync; did you forget to inherit a required module?”

Secondly, somewhere in the client project I need to specify the url for the servlet (something like http://localhost:8080/GWTServer/ gwtservice).  Basically, the environment needs to be set up such that when I call GWT.create(GWTService.class) it works.

Presumably I can set up this connection in the .xml configuration files in the client project.  But I have no idea how to do this.  And I don’t know if I need to make changes on the server side to the servlet definition.

The Server side web.xml which specifies the servlet follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GWTService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.gwtserver.server.GWTServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GWTService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/org.gwtserver.Server/gwtservice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcomeGWT.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I need to understand what I need to do in a client gwt application to communicate with the existing servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a GWT client to successfully interact with a GWT service, they **must** be compiled together at the same time and must be hosted at the same host for security reasons. You cannot build your own GWT client that accesses an existing GWT service that was compiled at a different time.

Your issue is actually separate from this, though. You cannot access a `jar` from the GWT client, since it requires that source code be in your source folders. Hence your `No source code is available` error. Once you solve that, though, you will see this: `Module needs to be (re)compiled`, which you will not be able to fix because of the reasons I mentioned in my first paragraph.